# How to cleanup tabs with vim, adjust sts and sw?

Tags: vim, refactoring, tabs

I created c++ files in vim with these tab settings

```
set sts=4
set sw=4
```

meanwhile i use

```
set sts=3
set sw=3
```

and want to change all the files.
Is this possible?

**EDIT**

I go with indent, a few other options come handy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of an automated way to do this with vim, but there's no reason you can't open up each of those files individually and use [`:retab!`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#%3aretab) to have them use your new settings.

If you want to re-indent a whole bunch of files at once, you may look into something like [GNU Indent](http://www.gnu.org/software/indent/).

Answer (score 1):

Not VIM-specific, but if you want to batch process all the source files in one shot, the [indent](http://www.gnu.org/software/indent/) command line tool is incredibly useful.